# Angular: Single page with multiple views on the same page

Tags: angular, view

I'm new to Angular 4 and trying to create a single page with 2 different view. Each of them have a component.ts, an html and a model.
I don't understand how to share variables between the two views. For example, the first view has a search panel with a button, when I click this button I call a service(not clear where call the service if on the first or second component) that returns a resulset.The second one must appear only if a result is provided.Thanks.

Comment: I think that you want share data between components really?

Comment: Yes, correct. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Create a common service to share the data and use router-outlet for the multi view

Comment: You need a service. Here's angular's tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Hello, you can create a service with an EventEmitter and implement the function that get the dataset, when data are ready you emit the event. In the component where you want to display the resultSet subscribe the event, so when data will be ready the component will be notified. In the search panel you only need to call method which get the dataset.